# New property in UIView extension for custom enum cases

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make some cases to apply on UIView, like changing the color with animating the new color or smoothly hiding the view

here I created small enum to hold all my animation cases :

```
enum ViewAnimation {
    case changeColor(to: UIColor, duration: TimeInterval)
    case hideView(duruation: TimeInterval)
}
```

And here I want to make a property for UIView :

```
extension UIView {


var animate: ViewAnimation {
    get {
        return .changeColor(to: .red, duration: 1) // actually I don't know what to add in the getter !
    }
    set {
        switch self.animate {
        case .changeColor(let newColor, let duration):
            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
                self.backgroundColor = newColor
            }
        case .hideView(let duration):
            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
                self.alpha = 0
                self.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

And here is my class :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let smallView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
    view.addSubview(smallView)
    smallView.backgroundColor = .red
    smallView.center = view.center

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
        smallView.animate = .changeColor(to: .blue, duration: 3)
    }
}
}
```

The problem is when I call `smallView.animate = .changeColor(to: .blue, duration: 3)` nothing change!

Any idea why it's not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you creating a property in the extension? You don't even need the getter.
Imho it's better to create a method.

```
extension UIView {
    func animate(animation: ViewAnimation) {
        switch animation {
        case .changeColor(let newColor, let duration):
            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
                self.backgroundColor = newColor
            }
        case .hideView(let duration):
            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
                self.alpha = 0
                self.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And call it `smallView.animate(animation: .changeColor(to: .blue, duration: 3))`

However, if you really want to use the property, you can't do `switch self.animate` because it will call the getter.
Try doing `switch newValue` because every `set` has an implicit local variable called `newValue` which is the current value assigned.

Answer (score 1):

you are checking the old value in your switch case.
you need to do this:

```
switch newValue {
    case .changeColor(let newColor, let duration):
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
            self.backgroundColor = newColor
        }
    case .hideView(let duration):
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
            self.alpha = 0
            self.isHidden = true
        }
    }
```

`newValue` is default if you implement set like `set{`
or you can do something like this:

```
set(abc){
  switch abc {
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the switch is actually calling the getter, thus always setting the background to red.

Test case:

```
var helpme: Int {
    get {
        return 1
    }
    set {
        switch helpme {
        default:
            print(helpme)
        }
    }
}

func testme() {
    helpme = 20
    print(helpme)
}

output:
1
1
```

---

```
    switch self.animate { //  calls the getter which returns red
    case .changeColor(let newColor, let duration):
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
            self.backgroundColor = newColor
        }
    case .hideView(let duration):
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
            self.alpha = 0
            self.isHidden = true
        }
    }
```

I think a property is too limited for the number of things you want to do.

I would suggest using a function for each of your animations and maybe having a property state animationType: AnimationType? if you want to know the current animation state of your view. Although this would require creating a new UIView class with the animationType property since you can't declare variables in extensions.

```
class AnimatingView: UIView {
  var animationType: AnimationType?
}


enum AnimationType {
  case changingColor
  case hidingView
}

func changeColor() {
  animationType = .changingColor
  // change color
}
```